# Проблемы со словом "значит"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, вводные-слова

В Большом толковом словаре на [Грамоте](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82&all=x), где говорится о слове "значит" как **вводном**, есть такой пример: *От воды идёт пар, **з.,** вода теплее воздуха.*
Тут же, где это слово является **союзом**, — такой: *Тучи собираются, **з.** будет дождь.*

Не понимаю, почему в первом примере "значит" — вводное? Чем этот пример отличается от второго?

В большой статье ([Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_220&layout=item)) приводятся "нормальные" примеры с этим вводным словом:
*Это, **значит**, и будет новый программист? Собираешься, **значит**, уезжать? Ты, **значит**, думаешь иначе?*
Здесь "значит" можно легко убрать из предложения, чего нельзя сказать о примере с водой.

И еще один момент.
В пункте 2 этой статьи написано: "Сближаясь по значению с вводными словами «следовательно», «таким образом», союз «значит» отделяется запятой (реже тире) от последующей части предложения". А в БТС, где союз, запятой нет. Как быть?

Comment: Роман, Вы не пробовали задать вопрос на Грамоте?

Comment: Я задавал давно несколько вопросов, как мне казалось стоящих внимания, но они не ответили.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, Грамоте не мешало бы чаще корректировать свои ответы и статьи. О том, что там встречаются ошибки и нестыковки, многие знают.

Статьи в популярных справочниках должны быть предельно понятны. Считаю, что предложение о воде, паре и воздухе неудачно в качестве примера с вводным словом, его не стоило включать. "Значит" в нём, действительно, тянет на союз.

По поводу союза и запятой после него сама же Грамота отвечает ([**Вопрос № 243900**](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=243900)):

> Союз *значит* (то же, что «и поэтому, следовательно») соединяет простые предложения в составе сложного. Запятая ставится перед союзом: *Тучи собираются, **значит** будет дождь. Ты сердишься, **значит** ты не прав.*

А в конце пишет следующее:

> Однако практика письма показывает, что слово *значит* **обычно выделяется знаками препинания почти во всех своих синтаксических функциях** (кроме функции сказуемого). Кроме того, во многих случаях возможны варианты пунктуации в одном и том же предложении. Ср. одинаково возможные: *Ревнует, значит (=и следовательно) любит; Ревнует – значит (=это) любит.* **В спорных случаях окончательное решение о расстановке знаков препинания принимает автор текста.**

На сайте lgram.ru тоже обращают внимание на эту же проблему ([**Ставится ли запятая перед и после «значит»**](https://lgram.ru/stavitsya-li-zapyataya-pered-i-posle-znachit/)):

> Однако есть некоторые расхождения в разных изданиях справочника по пунктуации, который выпущен коллективом портала «Грамота.ру».

Так что поставить запятую после союза "значит" можно (с союзом "впрочем", например, такая же ситуация – сближение в значении с вводным).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Ну так это не Грамота, это БТС (они не имеют права его редактировать).

Comment: @oleedd По крайней мере, они должны внимательно и педантично относиться к тому, что  представляют на **своей** площадке.

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае: от воды идёт пар, з., вода теплее воздуха, - переход от пара к понятию температуры и физическому феномену, который опускается и сразу пишется вывод: от воды идет пар -> феномен-> вода теплее воздуха. А во втором прямое соответствие/следствие без опосредованных моментов: тучи собираются = будет дождь - нет дыма без огня, нет дождя без туч. Ну и если уходить в физику, то вода может парить, и потому что воздух недостаточно увлажнён, парить может и холодная вода, и лед, и кипяток, так что равенство между этими явлениями поставить не получится. Но с другой стороны если вода горячая, она может испарить больше - не лучшей пример и лучше в физику не лезть и ставить запятую после "значит"-предположения.

На самом деле в БТС этот пункт перекопирован (частично) из словаря Ожегова.

А еще есть словарь Ефремовой, где есть уточнение по союзу, но нет примеров:

"1. Употребляется при присоединении придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения со значением следствия, соответствуя по значению сл.: следовательно, стало быть, поэтому, вследствие этого, в силу того что."

То есть:

"вода теплее воздуха, значит может пойти пар" - союз, потому что причина, а затем следствие. Можно заменить на "а значит".

"от воды идёт пар, з., вода теплее воздуха" - вообще не факт, значит вводное слово.

"Вещи собраны, з., уезжаете?" - предположение, когда вывод предполагает причину сборов. Ну и знак вопроса намекает на сомнения.

"Уезжаете, значит и вещи свои соберете," - союз, потому что причинно-следственная хронология событий не нарушена. Но можно и так сказать: вещи собраны, значит(действительно) уезжаете.

Не можете понять нужна ли запятая, значит, БТС писали буратины? Если сомнений нет, значит запятая не нужна. На самом деле, можно всё писать через утверждения, значит запятая нигде нужна не будет.

Правка.

*И я бы, вообще, развернул этот вопрос так: если есть запятая - значит слово не союз, а что-то еще "вводное". А если, есть тире перед, вместо запятой - это еще и определение. Вероятно, пунктуация связана с демонстрационной логической структурой, и обособляется то, что относится к собственному знанию, от общего знания. Но, кроме того, вводные слова и прочие "паразитические" конструкции - междометья, и типа того, на самом деле влияют на характер мысли. Если мысль ровная - то запятых почти не нужно, если же она с кучей "поворотов", то на каждом повороте, можно(нужно) делать паузу, не зависимо от того союз это или еще что.* Мысли буратины вслух, не обращайте внимания)

Comment: С одной стороны, я понимаю, о чем Вы говорите, а с другой - совсем не понимаю :). Про опускание феномена, например, что получается - он заменяется вводным словом? О феномене (кроме "воздух недостаточно увлажнен") Вы пишете: "парить может и горячая вода, а кипяток - так вообще" - это же и говорит о том, что вода теплее воздуха. Но спасибо за внимание к вопросу и ответ!

Comment: А, ну я тоже запутался, лед тоже может парить - сублимация льда или возгонка. То есть парение - зависит не от температуры, а от уровня насыщенности воздуха водяным паром. Но от горячей воды еще воздух нагревается и поэтому он может принять больше пара. Пока писал, забыл что писал. Я так понял, если уверены в том, что пишите, то не ставите запятую(или вместо передней запятой вообще можно ставить тире), если подразумевается сомнение или есть прямой вопрос - то запятая нужна и это вводное слово, которое по сути "коробочка" с вашими субъективными выводами, а не истиной или объективным правилом.

Comment: В общем, чтобы не лезть в физические дебаты, лучше поставить запятую)

Answer (score 1):

Например, если взять слово ‟впрочем”, то оно имеет такое же значение, что и союз ‟но”, но при этом имеет такую же интонацию отступления, как и вводные. Чем считать слово ‟впрочем” – это вопрос промежуточного строительства терминологии, то есть когда есть характеристики двух терминов, а чем считать – мы просто решаем условно (хоть подбрасыванием монетки), если это вообще нам нужно. Со словом ‟значит” нет такого, потому что в таких предложениях ‟значит”, как и многие вводные, – это вводное и неполное предложение одновременно (это значит). Конечно же вводные предложения должны обособляться! Конечно же здесь просто грубая ошибка!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!